# ApplyFilter in macro to not filter if empty

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have a form where I can log bookings which looks along the lines of:

```
PNR ¦ Date Booking Created ¦ Name of Customer
---------------------------------------------
1   ¦ 01/03/16             ¦ Marc N
2   ¦ 04/07/16             ¦ Sam D
3   ¦ 13/02/17             ¦ Max L
```

Where PNR is the ID field.
At the top of the form I have a search bar which searches and returns the Name using a simple macro (connected to an 'on click' button) comparing the search bar LIKE [Name of Customer].

I also have two search bars next to each other, which dates are put in, and using a macro (also connected to an 'on click' button) it finds WHERE [DateFrom]<[Date Booking Created]<[DateTo] which when clicked shows all results between the two inputted dates.

However i'm not sure how I can create a macro where it 'ApplyFilter''s both of them at the same time. I initially coppied the "Where" code from both button scripts and put them both connected to one button which when clicked runs a macro where it 'ApplyFilter' Both of them (With an AND seperating them).

However this doesnt work well, as if I decide just to search for a name, it doesnt show any results as the [DateFrom] and [DateTo] search bar is empty, how would i approach such a situation (preferably in a macro) so that it returns records even if I just search for a name with no date constrictions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write VBA code that generates your filter based on the contents of the various filter elements. Here is an example of VBA code that does this:

```
Dim Filter As String
Filter = ""
If Nz(Me.fCustomerName)<>"" Then
    Filter = Filter & "CustomerName Like '" & Me.fCustomerName & "*' AND "
  End If
If IsDate(Me.DateFrom) Then
    Filter = Filter & "DateCreated >= #" & Me.DateFrom & "# AND "
  End If
If Len(Nz(Me.DateTo, "")) Then
    Filter = Filter & "DateCreated <= #" & Me.DateTo & "# AND "
  End If
If Filter <> "" Then
    Filter = Left(Filter, Len(Filter) - 5)
    Me.Filter = Filter
    Me.FilterOn = True
  Else
    Me.FilterOn = False
  End If
Me.Requery
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How would I go about attaching this to a button to run when clicked? Also if you could do a brief explanation of what's going on so I can adapt the script it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You add it to the button's On Click event. As to what is going on, the code is actually very simple and self explanatory, assuming you can read VBA. If you can't read VBA no explanation I could give you would help. But I will try. The code checks the contents on 3 form controls, one text and two date ones and generates a string that is an SQL-like filter (the WHERE part of an SQL statement). That's the first 3 Ifs. The last one check if there is any filter generated and if there is assigns it as the filter to the form and activates it, otherwise it turns the filer off.

Comment: The only maybe not easy part is `Filter = Left(Filter, Len(Filter) - 5)` which basically removes the " AND " part from the end of the filter. Since we don't know in advance how many "ANDs" we will need, each control that has a value adds "AND" by default, which always results in one excess "AND" at the end.